# Convergence of the series $\sum \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^5}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like your help in proving whether this series converges\divergers:

$$ \sum \frac{1}{\ln^5(n)} $$

any advice?

Comment: Is the denominator $(\log(n))^{5}$ or $\log\log\log\log\log(n)$?

Comment: For sufficiently large $n$, $\ln^5(n) < n$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: @Matsuda, why is this part  true? $ ln^5(n)<n $

Comment: @segevp One way to see it is to note that $$\lim_{n} \frac{(\log n)^5}{n} = 0$$.

Comment: @segevp, how about $ln^5(n) / n$ get limit as n tends to infinity by repeated use of l'hopital rule

Comment: Or, the more intuitive route, look at what happens to $(\ln n)^5$ as you square the input $n$. It clearly grows much slower than squaring, once $n$ becomes large enough.

Comment: Notice that if $a>1$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log_a n}{n^p}=0, \quad \forall p \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comments one has $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log_a n}{n^p}=0, \quad \forall p >0.$$
one can find $N$ such that $$n^{\frac{1}{5}}>\log n\quad \forall n\geq N$$ or, $$\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{\ln ^5 n}.$$ So by comparison test the series diverges.

Comment: great! thank you so much!